# After upgrading from Windows 7 a device driver no longer works

Tags: drivers, windows-8

I have an Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver that I ordered from China. I believe it's a counterfeit as Microsoft had already discontinued the device long before I bought it. Because of this I believe the driver's inf file was modified by the seller.

This wasn't a problem in Windows 7, but the device showed up as "Unknown device" after upgrading to Windows 8 Pro x64.

Now, when I try to install the drivers I get this error:
[image]
*The hash for the file is not present in the specified catalog file. The file is likely corrupt or the victim of tampering.*

How can I get Windows to ignore this issue and take the driver?

Comment: Get China on the phone, ask for a working W8 driver!

Comment: You should consider getting an authentic driver from Microsoft instead.

Comment: @kinokijuf There simply isn't one for this device.

Comment: What are the device IDs and compatible device IDs for it? (You can find out using the device manager)

Comment: @kinokijuf HW ID: `USB\VID_045E&PID_0291&REV_0107`
Compatible ID: `USB\Class_FF&SubClass_5D&Prot_81`
Device ID: `USB\VID_045E&PID_0291`

Comment: No, please write the content of BOTH the lines “Hardware ID” and “Compatible ID” there are ony two fields in device manager, not three

Comment: @kinokijuf Those are in [HW ID](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kJuiZ.png) and [Compatible ID](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vxiqX.png) above. I couldn't find the "device ID" so I gave you the [`Matching device ID`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JdsZ5.png).

Comment: Looks as if the thing you got is not an official receiver from Microsoft, but rather a cannibalised part of a broken Xbox that there are no drivers for.

Comment: @kinokijuf Yeah, the part was already discontinued (repackaged as only available with a 360 controller "for Windows"), so I was hoping these were surplus. It's probably reverse engineered or something.

Comment: @Louis The thing you have got is not even an official Microsoft device.

Comment: @kinokijuf Yes, [it is](http://web.archive.org/web/20121103210135/http://www.microsoft.com/games/en-US/Hardware/Controllers/Pages/XboxWirelessGamingReceiverforWindows.aspx/). I have a counterfeit. Of course, I didn't realize that until I tried to install the drivers from Microsoft's site, rather than the ones that came with the receiver.

Comment: Can you return the product as defective?

Comment: @kinokijuf Probably not. But it works well, and I wouldn't want to try it if I could, as the seller is in China and I'm in the US.

Comment: …what? You bought something from **China**? Are there no local computer stores where you live? In this case sorry, but you deserve what you got.

Comment: @kinokijuf The internet is my local PC store. If by deserve you mean saving $40 and being able to use my XBox 360 controller on my PC, I'd agree.

Comment: @Louis You really trust random strangers from a totalitarian country?

Comment: @kinokijuf I don't trust random strangers anywhere. If my purchase is protected by companies like PayPal, I feel comfortable buying inexpensive items from overseas. I would've gotten it from Microsoft, but they discontinued it for obvious financial reasons. It was simple decision for me: buy a receiver bundled with a new controller, which I did't need, or just buy the receiver. I gladly gave the Chinese seller my business. Imagine if a tablet maker stopped selling styluses, saying you can only get them with a new tablet. Would you buy the tablet to get the stylus? Or get the stylus from China?

Comment: @Louis But **what you bought is not a MSFT product**.

Comment: @kinokijuf I'm not sure I see what you're getting at. I've known it's a copy for years, as indicated in the opening of my question over a year ago.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lusitanian's method didn't work for me this time in Windows 8.1. But this did:

- <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> and enter "change advanced startup options".
- Then click Restart Now.
- Follow the Troubleshooting options until you reach Advanced Boot Options.
- Finally choose **Disable Driver Signing Enforcement** and install the drivers.

It will be renabled upon a fresh reboot.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to install the driver.
Open a command prompt as an Administrator and run the following two commands:

```
bcdedit -set loadoptions DISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS
bcdedit -set TESTSIGNING ON
```

Restart your computer. When you reboot, you'll be able to install any unsigned or test-signature-signed drivers without a hitch. The downside of this is that it leaves you open to security holes, so after you're done installing the driver, re-enable the integrity checks:

```
bcdedit -set loadoptions ENABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS
bcdedit -set TESTSIGNING OFF
```

Alternatively, you could check if the [Driver Signature Overrider](http://www.ngohq.com/home.php?page=dseo) tool works under Win8.

Comment: The bcdedit method worked for me. Note: The drivers are actually signed. It seems that Windows 8 now detects if they've been tampered with though.